# Possible to change the spacing around MaterialCheckBox?

Tags: android, material-components, material-components-android

I'm curious to know whether it's possible to change the default spacing that's placed around `MaterialCheckBox`... or whether there are plans to allow for this.

Let's say, for the sake of example, I have a `CheckBox` defined with four `TextViews` around it (to the left, right, top and bottom of it) and I specify no margins on any of the five `Views`. If I define my app's theme as `Theme.AppCompat.Light` then this `CheckBox` is rendered with equal spacing around it as follows:

[image: CheckBox as rendered in Theme.AppCompat.Light theme]

If I change the app's theme to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light` and make no other changes to the app then the `CheckBox` is rendered as follows:

[image]

Note the unequal spacing which I would like to customise on a per-need basis. There's nothing mentioned in the `MaterialCheckBox` [documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Checkbox.md) and I can't see anything obvious in the [class definition](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/checkbox/MaterialCheckBox.java) about being able to change this spacing.

(For what it's worth I'm using the latest version of the `com.google.android.material:material library`, i.e. `1.1.0-alpha03`. And everything I've said above holds regardless of whether I define a `CheckBox`, `AppCompatCheckBox` or `MaterialCheckBox` in my layout. The key thing is changing the theme from `Theme.AppCompat.Light` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light`.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks related to MaterialCheckBox enforcing a 48dp minTouchTargetSize for accessibility using android:minWidth in the CheckBox style (this should be added to the documentation). Setting android:minWidth to 0dp should work.

Comment: what if i have custom checbox class?